# How to fix 'JsonNull cannot be cast to JsonObject'

Tags: java, json, gson

I call a post API which responds with details on specific addresses, however some of the responses that get returned have no data so they'll be returned as null. How do I stop the casting error in my code?

I currently only get the data as a Json Object and I'm not sure how to rework my code that so when a JsonNull Element gets returned I can handle that data.

```
JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString);
JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
jsonObject = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("response"); // This is either an object or it is null 

String buildName = jsonObject.get("buildingName").getAsString();
String buildNum = jsonObject.get("premisesNumber").getAsString();
String streetName = jsonObject.get("streetName").getAsString();
```

What I expect to be returned would be either the address details for valid addresses or no information at all for the invalid addresses.

The error that gets produced is this: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonNull cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: Use `.getString(key, defaultValue)` and set a default for the case there is no data

Answer (score 2):

Before getAsString() check for isJsonNull(). It'll return true if object is Null.

You can rewrite your code as below

```
String buildName= (jsonObject.get("buildingName").isJsonNull ?  null : jsonObject.get("buildingName").getAsString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally is a good idea validate the data is JSON valid

```
    public static boolean isJSONValid(String test) {
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        try {
            new JSONArray(test);
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Function above will return you true in case the string is a valid JSON object(could be an object or an array of objects).

After that you can continue parsing using Jackson lib or the GSON lib